List with elements and lists to data.frame
I am new to R coming from Python. I have a list which contains single elements and lists. How do I unnest the list and convert it to a data.frame.
Here is an example:
# My nested list
complexList <- list(distance=1, 
                    activity=list(key=2, id="a"), 
                    other=12, 
                    stuff=list(a=3, b=4))

# Desired output
  distance activity.key activity.id other stuff.a stuff.b
1        1            2           a    12       3       4 

Note: I have a list of many of these lists. Each unnested list should then become one row in a dataframe.

data.frame(complexList) ?

Just wrapping it in data.frame would give you the expected output.
data.frame(complexList)

#  distance activity.key activity.id other stuff.a stuff.b
#1        1            2           a    12       3       4

